# UIView in tableFooterView property doesn't fit inside UITabelView's scrollview

Tags: ios, uitableview

I set the tableFooterView of my tableView like this:

```
UIView *footerView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 44)];
UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
[button setFrame:CGRectMake(10, 10, footerView.bounds.size.width - 20, 44)];
[button setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"addItemButton.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(add) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[footerView addSubview:button];
self.tableView.tableFooterView = footerView;
```

However, when I scroll to the very bottom of my tableview, my button is cut off.

How can I make sure that the entire button is shown?

Answer (score 2):

Question doesn't state if button is cut of by scrollview not scrolling down enough. But if that's the case you have to change UITableViews (UIScrollView) contentsize.

```
CGSize wholesize =  self.tableView.contentSize;

wholesize.height = self.tableView.contentSize.height + self.tableView.tableFooterView.frame.size.height;

self.tableView.contentSize = wholesize;
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I wish I could give this 100,000 upvotes. Been banging my head on this for hours.